# Error "The hierarchy of the type ClassName is inconsistent" in spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

```
package com.nit.aop.advices;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.springframework.aop.MethodBeforeAdvice;

public class LoggingBeforeAdvice implements MethodBeforeAdvice
{

    @Override
    public void before(Method arg0, Object[] arg1, Object arg2)
            throws Throwable {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

when i execute this programme that time i was getting error -"The hierarchy of the type ClassName is inconsistent" so now i want to remove this error

Comment: What are you doing? What is the exception stacktrace? You're even not asking a question here…

Answer (score 5):

If you write a class A inherits B and B inherits C, such as fruit or C interface c cited jar is not your bag, they reported this information, you can import the jar package. 
In this program code is Me thodBeforeAdvice parent class is not org.springframework.aop, you need to **aopalliance-1.0.jar** package can be imported into your project .

Download from the http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0

From this Jar File I run program properly....

Comment: Worked for me! This should be considered the final answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

actually it happens when jre file libraries missing. so i added jre jar files and it runs fine.